# Minimal dimension for $ PSU_3 $ as a matrix group.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

$ SU_2 $ is a subgroup of $ GL_2(\mathbb{C}) $. $ PSU_2 $ is not. However $ PSU_2 \cong SO_3(\mathbb{R}) $ is a subgroup of $ GL_3(\mathbb{C}) $.

$ SU_3 $ is a subgroup of $ GL_3(\mathbb{C}) $. **What is the smallest $ k $ such that $ PSU_3 $ is a subgroup of $ GL_k(\mathbb{C}) $?**

For any $ n $, $ SU_n $ has dimension $ n^2-1 $ so the adjoint representation realizes $ PSU_n $ as a subgroup of $ SO_{n^2-1}(\mathbb{R}) $ which in turn is contained inside of $ GL_{n^2-1}(\mathbb{C}) $.

In particular that means we have the containments $ PSU_3 \leq SO_8 \leq SU_8 \leq  GL_8(\mathbb{C}) $.

My intuition is that the adjoint representation $ n^2-1 $ should always be the smallest dimension containing $ PSU_n $ as a matrix subgroup. However I know this is not true for all simple groups. For example the exceptional group $ G_2 $ has dimension $ 14 $ but already has a faithful representation in dimension $ 7 $.

If $ SU_3 $ is inside of $ GL_k $ then it must be in the maximal compact subgroup $ U_k $ and in fact in the maximal semi-simple compact $ SU_k $. So the question really becomes what is the least $ k $ such that $ PSU_3 $ is a subgroup of $ SU_k $? I know that $ k $ is at most $ 8 $.

Comment: Very interesting question! My intuition is different from yours. I think $n^2 - 1$ is HUGE compared to $n$ and that we only need a linear increase in dimension (as opposed to quadratic) to deal with this tiny tiny finite center misbehaving and preventing the standard representation of $SU_n$ to become a representation of $PSU_n$. However, my intuition has deceived me before. I am looking very much forward to someone more knowledgeable to write an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 8.

Indeed in dimension $\le 7$ the irreducible complex representations of $\mathrm{SL}_3$ are known (see Fulton's book): they have dimension 3 (the standard one and its dual), 6 (their symmetric squares). The previous ones are faithful. So $\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbf{C})$ has no nontrivial representation of dimension $\le 7$.

If we have a complex representation of $\mathrm{PSU}(3)$, by passing to the complexification we get a representation of $\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbf{C})$ on the same space. It the space has dimension $\le 7$ the resulting representation is hence trivial, hence trivial on $\mathrm{PSU}(3)$ as well.